# Are blocks supported in iPhone OS 3.1.3?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to use Objective-C blocks in an iPhone 3.1.3 app but am getting a linkage error:

```
"_NSConcreteGlobalBlock," referenced from:
```

Any ideas as to whether blocks are supported in the iPhone 3.1.3 SDK?  I found conflicting reports on the internet.

Comment: iPhone 3.3? Do you work for Apple or something?

Comment: How did you get iPhone OS 3.3?  Do you work for Apple?  If you do you're asking the wrong people.  Maybe you mean iPhone OS 3.1.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocks are *not* supported natively on the iPhone.  However, there is an option:  The "plblocks" project allows you to compile block-based code for 10.5 and iPhone OS 2.2+:

- http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/ (project)
- http://github.com/zakovyrya/iPhone-blocks (example of use on iPhone)

Comment: Thanks, I think they might be supported in the 3.2 beta according to the plblocks blog.  I need to download it to see.