# call a function in place in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i would like to define a selector in place. How can i do so?

i.e. I would like to do something like this:

```
 [self performSelector:@selector( function() {variable = 3;} ) withObject:self afterDelay:3];
```

where `variable` is an int of the class calling the function.

Comment: you might have a look at [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1):

```
int multiplier = 7; 
int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) 
{
    return num * multiplier;
};

printf("%d", myBlock(3));
// prints "21"
```

Apple provides block-based APIs for a lot of operations where @selector callbacks were the only options in the past. Note that blocks are available only in iOS 4.0 and newer (although there exist [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529973/are-blocks-supported-in-iphone-os-3-1-3) to allow using block-based code with older iOS versions).

Edit: Added a more 'real-world' example of calling a block after a given time:

```
dispatch_time_t  delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_after(delay, queue, ^{variable = 3});
```

Note that this example uses the [grand central dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) which is also available only for iOS 4.0 and newer.

Comment: Block are definitely the path to the solution. However, HOW would you use the above block (NOT in `printf`) in the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method, as suggested by the OP?

Comment: Instead of calling the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, you could use the Grand Central Dispatch (which is also a iOS >= 4.0 feature) and write something like that: `dispatch_time_t  delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_after(delay, queue, block);`

Answer (score 0):

For the extra effort involved with GCD for such a non-trivial task, you may as well create a separate method:

```
- (void) setVariable:(NSNumber *) value
{
    variable = [value intValue];
}

- (void) someOtherMethod
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(setVariable:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

You *could* use blocks or GCD but this gives you a solution *plus* backwards compatibility. The only downside is that `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` doesn't have the best resolution (e.g. it may execute after 3.2 seconds, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Insert code here
}];
```